# NSNumberFormatter Won't Accept Zeros After a Decimal Point

Tags: ios, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber, decimal-point

Similar questions have been asked but I find that the offered solutions don't work with the latest iOS SDK or are not exactly applicable in this particular case.

I call a method using an NSNotification, that formats a number with grouping symbols in a UILabel as it is entered using digits from button input. It works great for integers and decimals too--so long as no zeros are entered after a decimal point. For example if 2000 is entered, it is displayed as 2,000 as it is entered just fine. If 23.345 is entered, that displays just fine too. Any calculations done on these numbers come out correct. But it is impossible to enter 0.0001 or 0.2340007! It just won't take and append any zeros after the decimal point.

I got the original code idea from another post here at stackoverflow:

```
NSString *currentText = [display_ text];
currentText = [currentText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@","
               withString:@""];
currentText = [currentText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." 
               withString:@"."];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:10];

NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:currentText];

NSString *finalText = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];

NSString *lastChar = [currentText substringFromIndex:[currentText length] - 1]; 

if ([lastChar isEqualToString:@"."]) 
{
 finalText = [finalText stringByAppendingString:@"."];
}

[display_ setText: finalText];
[formatter release];
```

No amount of finagling (that I have tried) with the parameters of the formatter will allow the entry of zeros after the decimal point.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you replace "." with "."? What do you see in debugger after number is instantiated?

I have never worked with NSDecimalNumber but struggled already with doubles some time ago. I would suggest breaking down the problem. Instantiate `number` with a hard-coded value, format it and write it to log file. If this doesn't work try my code below, it works fine in my app with double values. I am using German locale settings but that shouldn't be the point.

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setAllowsFloats:TRUE];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMinimumSignificantDigits:20];
[formatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:20];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:5];
NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1000.0123f];
myTextField.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

If your code does work already,

- check that there is no O instead of zero
- Remove this "." replacement mentioned above
- I found out that setting a locale explicitly solved some problems (it's too long ago to remember details but you might give it a try)
- Replace NSDecimalNumber by NSNumber and feed it with double values
- Check your XIB file and ensure that your text field does not perform any other formatting

Comment: Thank's @Kay. I've tried most of your ideas previously. Your code works for a hard coded value, but fails when numbers are entered sequentially. You're correct in that I do not need to replace "." with "." but it doesn't make it work any better. Using your idea and `NSLocale* locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; [formatter setLocale:locale]; NSNumber* number = [formatter numberFromString:[display_ text]]; NSString *finNum = [formatter stringFromNumber: number]; [display_ setText:finNum ];` it won't accept decimal points and it clears after 4 digits. Same if number is from doubleValue.

Comment: hard coded with NSDecimal or NSNumber? ...after 4 digits? hmmh, maximumFraction is set as 5, strange. Are you working on the device or in simulator? What is your locale? Have you tried to force US locale?

Comment: Tried with both NSDecimal and NSNumber. I tried to force US locale (I'm in the US). It's on the simulator. I have come up with what I would call a "work-around." In my input method I call the displayDidChange method every time the input string is appended UNLESS there is a decimal point present. Under these conditions, the formatter formats the integer grouping separators, and the decimal numbers are input without a problem so long as the displayDiDChange method isn't called again. Previously formatted grouping separators are maintained. The "if" statement is then no longer needed either.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you found a work-around. +1 as comfort for finding your own solution :-)